# Passing Access Token facebook 3 for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

In my app I'm using new facebook SDK (3). From the main Activity user can click different buttons, after click new Activity is started and shows different lists: one with messages, second with friend requests and third with notifications. Everything works fine with first two cases but when I want to show notifications by making graphpath request like:

```
Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, "me/notifications?include_read=true",
                new Request.Callback() {}
```

I get an error:

> {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: **An
>   active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user**.}, isFromCache:false}

I've already asked for read permissions (read_mailbox, read_requests) and for publish permission (manage_notifications). I think I have to pass an access token to my activity with notifications list but I don't know how to do that, thanks for help

**Solution**

I found the solution, it's just we can't put parameters such as "include_read=true" directly to graphpath request, we have to make a new Request object with these parameters: session, httpmethod, parameters, graphpath, callback.

Comment: Your assessment is correct - you need to provide an access token.  What have you tried?

Comment: nothing, I don't know how to save access Token in one activity and then open it in other

Comment: To be more specific, I know there is a class "AccessToken" with "getToken()" method, however I don't know how to use it (create it). Than I'm assuming I have to save access Token, which I obtained I open it in my second activity with this method "Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(context, accessToken, callback)"

Comment: You don't need to deal directly with access tokens anymore in SDK v3. Just pass in the session and it should work. Since Session.getActiveSession() is a static, you can access it from any activity.

Comment: but it's not working when I use Session.getActiveSession I can't read notifications (works fine with read_mailbox, read_requests), I'm getting an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Janek for answering your own question, as you mentioned the parameters need to be sent separately and not as part of the graphPath, I am just posting an example of your solution in case someone has the same issue:

```
new Request(session, "me", getRequestParameters(), null, new Request.Callback() { ... }).executeAsync();

   private Bundle getRequestParameters() {
      Bundle parameters = new Bundle(1);
         parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture");
         return parameters;
   }
```

Comment: I am using this method. It resolves the error due to token but am getting an empty array of data when trying to access the friend list.